# Is Evelyn pronounced variously based on gender?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, names

When I first read Evelyn Waugh's books decades ago, I assumed the author was female. I subsequently found out Evelyn can also be a man's name in England. But today I found out that Evelyn Waugh's first wife was also named Evelyn. What I'd like to know is, were both of their names pronounced the same — with a long E for the first syllable ("E-vil-un"), or is the female Evelyn pronounced in England the same way Americans say it ("EV-uh-len")?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the tag "British-English" to reach more people! I wish I could help, but I'm not experienced with British/American pronunciations.

Comment: I don't know, but I see this clue at lithub.com:  *Despite the fact that Waugh’s real first name was Arthur, their friends referred to them as “He-Evelyn” and “She-Evelyn.”* [Fun fact: Evelyn Waugh’s first wife was also named Evelyn](https://lithub.com/fun-fact-evelyn-waughs-first-wife-was-also-named-evelyn/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It often has to do with if it's a man's name or a woman's name, either in British English or American English.  But proper names can be pronounced any way you want. Ever.  Conventions change.  The origins vary.

From Wikipedia:

> The name originally was used as a surname, which derived from Aveline,
> a feminine Norman French diminutive of the name Ava.[2] Ava itself is
> a hypocoristic Germanic name, of uncertain origin.[3]
>
> Evelyn is also sometimes used as an Anglicisation of the Irish
> Aibhilín or Éibhleann.[4] Aibhilín (variant Eibhlín) is itself derived
> from the Norman French Aveline. Éibhleann (variant Éibhliu[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Waugh)), on the
> other hand, is said to be derived from the Old Irish óiph
> ("beauty"[5]).

Those have a long /i/, counterintuitive to modern Eve vs Ève.

> Pronunciation /ˈɛvʌlɪn/, /ˈiːvlɪn/

The man's first name is more popular in BrE with a TREE vowel. I wondered about this in chat a while back (pending review from the answer I got there) when reading *Decline and Fall* again.

The writer, a man, pronounced his  name Arthur [Evelyn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Waugh) St. John Waugh (/ˈiːvlɪn ˈsɪndʒən ˈwɔː/. Men
of this first name tend to pronounce their own first names with a TREE vowel.  Women with it tend to pronounce their own first names with an EGG vowel.   Last names are usually the man's name like the household brand items of Crabtree and Evelyn, which is from New England and now pronounced either way, but more often with a long /i/.

Comment: The syllable count isn't always the same.

Comment: That is the basis for a lot of it.  Even r insertion for the woman's name, "ever-lyn" because of syllables.

Comment: The man's name isn't popular at all in BrE. Ambiguous names like Hilary and Vivian are seldom used by men these days (though who knows what will happen with the current fashion for gender fluidity!). AFAIK the woman's name, not very common either, is pronounced with the TREE vowel.

Comment: Regarding syllables, I'd expect two syllables with a long /i/ at the start, and more likely 3 syllables with /ɛ/ but I don't know if that matches how others pronounce it (certainly reducing the middle syllable is likely).

Comment: @KateBunting He was writing over a hundred years ago into the 1960s, with an open letter to Nancy Mitford I highly recommend.  Ashley Wilkes and I agree with you, not so popular a boy's name now.  Some sites show Evelyn for baby girls hit the top ten in the last five years in the US.